# Is it possible to access cameras like wide, normal and telephoto using flutter camera package (https://pub.dev/packages/camera)

Tags: camera

I am working on a project and using flutter camera package. I would like to use iphone's wide camera and telephoto camera, is it possible using this package?

i tried to look into the methods of the package and none of them were working for me, would like to know if someone has used it

Answer (score 0):

You can actually choose which camera to use now.

```
List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();
CameraDescription camera = cameras[$YourDesiredCamera]
```

Take iPhone14 as example, 0,1,2,3 will be default back, front, telephoto, and ultrawide respectively.

I do want to mention when I tried cameras instead of the default main camera, functions do not work smooth as they should.